# Darboux-like coordinates on a Kähler manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

If $(M, g, J, \Omega)$ is a Kähler manifold, do there exist local coordinates in which 2 out of the 3 geometrical structures look nice? I have Darboux coordinates in which $\Omega$ looks nice, but they don't tell me anything about $g$ and $J$ (or do they?). I also have normal coordinates for $g$, but now I know nothing about the form of $J$ and $\Omega$. Is it possible to find coordinates, say, in which both $\Omega$ and $J$ should take their standard forms from $\Bbb R ^{2n}$, or something in this spirit?

(In fact, I wonder whether there exist coordinates in which the Christoffel coefficients of the natural Levi-Civita connection be $0$.)

Comment: No, I don't think so. Remember that any two determine the other one, so already it seems unlikely. Normal coordinates for g are not really very nice; they are not much use compared to Darboux coordinates or complex coordinates. However, the Christoffel coefficients vanish at the origin in normal coordinates for g.

Comment: @BenMcKay: Concerning my last question, it has almost surely a negative answer: if Chistoffel's coefficients were $0$ on an open subset, then the complex projective space with the Fubini-Study metric would have curvature $0$, which is known not to be the case. Nevertheless, the rest of my question, being independent of this, still stands.

Comment: One of the characteristic properties of Kähler manifolds is the existence of *normal holomorphic coordinates*, that is, holomorphic coordinates $(z_1,\ldots ,z_n)$ (at each point) such that the metric can be written $\sum dz_id\bar{z}_i+$ terms of higher order. See for instance [these lectures](http://moroianu.perso.math.cnrs.fr/tex/kg.pdf), Theorem 5.6.

Comment: @abx: Yes, and I suspect that the terms of higher order and their derivatives cancel at the origin of the system of coordinates, like for Riemannian non-holomorphic normal coordinates. Still, this does not make computations significantly easier.

Comment: The higher order terms are computed from the curvature. In particular, they do not typically vanish.

Comment: I do not know why do you need such coordinate system. But keep in mind that in Kahler manifolds there is something more primitive than the metric called "potential". If your metric is Kahler analytic, then as Calabi did you can single out a nice potential (called diastasis) that perhaps can be useful for you when writen in suitable coordinates: http://loi.sc.unica.it/articoli/bochner.pdf.

Comment: @RuadhaíDervan: They do not vanish locally, or they do not vanish at a point (the center of the coordinate system)? Usually, the defining property of Riemannian normal coordinates is that, *at the center*, the metric is Euclidean and the derivative of the metric vanishes. Are things different for holomorphic normal coordinates?

Comment: I was referring to the Bochner co-ordinates in my comments, so probably Holonomia's comment clarifies this.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's the complex structure that's most important to keep track of easily. So the most common coordinates used in calculations are holomorphic coordinates $z^1, \dots, z^n, \bar{z}^1, \dots, \bar{z}^n$, and the Kähler metric is represented using its potential function. Normal coordinates are more useful in real Riemannian geometry, because they are connected to Jacobi fields. I can imagine that in some circumstances Darboux coordinates are useful. Another alternative is to use a unitary frame of $(1,0)$-forms and not coordinates.  Try all of them and see which works best.

Comment: @AlexM. at the center of Bochner's coordinates all Christoffel coefficients are zero. They do not vanish locally otherwise your metric is locally flat (as you know)  because this implies the vanishing of the curvature tensor.